# Issue with string cleanup in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas column that contains rows of words that are surrounded in quotes, brackets or nothing, like this:

```
"cxxx"
[asdfasd]
asdfasdf
[asdf]
"asdf"
```

My problem is that the below code is stripping the first and last characters from the elements that don't have quotes or brackets and I'm not sure why.

```
def keyword_cleanup(x):
    if "\"" or "[" in x:
        return x[1:-1]
    else:
        return x


csv["Keyword"] = csv["Keyword"].apply(keyword_cleanup)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if "\"" or "[" in x:
```

should be

```
if "\"" in x or "[" in x:    # x must contain a left bracket or double-quote.
```

or

```
if x.startswith(('"', '[')): # x must start with a left-braket or double-quote
```

since Python parses the former as

```
if ("\"") or ("[" in x):
```

due to the `in` operator binding more tightly than `or`. (See [Python operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).)

Since any non-empty string such as `"\""` has boolean truth value `True`, the `if-statement`'s condition is always True, and that is why 
`keyword_cleanup` was always returning `x[1:-1]`.

---

However, also note that Pandas has [string operators builtin](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#vectorized-string-methods). Using them will be far faster than using `apply` to call a custom Python function for each item in the Series.

```
In [136]: s = pd.Series(['"cxxx"', '[asdfasd]', 'asdfasdf', '[asdf]', '"asdf"'])

In [137]: s.str.replace(r'^["[](.*)[]"]$', r'\1')
Out[137]: 
0        cxxx
1     asdfasd
2    asdfasdf
3        asdf
4        asdf
dtype: object
```

If you want to strip *all* brackets or double quotes from both ends of each string, you could instead use

```
In [144]: s.str.strip('["]')
Out[144]: 
0        cxxx
1     asdfasd
2    asdfasdf
3        asdf
4        asdf
dtype: object
```

Comment: The first option works great for me.  Question: why does my initial code remove first and last characters from strings that don't contain a bracket or quotes, as python parses like this `if ("\"") or ("[" in x):`

Comment: You can also pass tuples to `str.startswith()`: `x.startswith(('"', '['))`

Comment: @msvalkon: Thanks very much for the improvement.

Comment: Thanks for all of the great answers

Comment: ^[" means replace [ or " at the beginning, right? What does [] after that correspond to? Thanks.

Comment: @julieth: Yes, the `^` matches the start of the string. `["[]` is a character class composed of the characters `"` and `[`. The *outer brackets* indicate it is a [character class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).